# Improving on counterpoint questions in digest format

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation

We've had a recent influx of very interesting counterpoint-related questions (as well as some excellent answers), but I want to improve on the way they are being asked, so this post is designed to bring up a few reminders, and help us as a community do a bit of housekeeping.

- https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10774/few-questions-on-counterpoint-in-the-tradition-of-johan-fux

The above question is on-topic and answerable, but is being asked in a manner that treats this site a bit too much like a forum, as it is essentially a digest or list of questions that the asker presumedly came up with over the course of the day's study.

What we should shoot for instead are individual questions whose title offers an answerable summary. This has the following benefits:

- The questions themselves are much more search engine-friendly
- The individual questions are much more approachable by people who don't have the expertise to answer the complete digest, so you will get more answers
- The question answerers get more upvotes and reputation for their answers than they would on a single question-answer pair
- The associated question tags (in this case, [counterpoint](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counterpoint)) will look more comprehensive and approachable

I want to improve the question above and have it broken out into its component individual questions, so I'm temporarily closing until we can clean it up. That question should be edited to contain just one of the four questions, three new questions should be created, and they should all be titled in a descriptive way. After that's done, I'll reopen the edited original question. @Chris Olszewski should post an answer to this question with the new question links once they are split up.

User @jjmusicnotes will have to do the same with his answers to that question at that time, but hopefully he won't mind the free upvotes from some simple copy/pasting. `:)`

For an example of how these might be titled, I edited the following question's title since its component questions were all small enough and related to the same concepts: [Beginning counterpoint above or below a cantus firmus](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10773/few-questions-on-study-of-counterpoint)

And lastly:

- [Accidentals in First Species Counterpoint](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/one-more-question-about-a-passage-from-the-study-of-counterpoint-by-johann-fux)

This is one more question that could possibly be improved, but I don't have the expertise in this area to know for sure how cohesive it is. This post should also solicit suggestions as to whether or not anything should be done with it. For example, perhaps the OP or answerer would be able to suggest a better title for the question if the material is all about a specific topic, similar to what I did with the previous example.

Comment: I agree completely and would be happy to transfer my answers to each individual question once they have been split. I'll also look to see if I can help improve the questions / titles so they are more helpful / specific.

Comment: Just wanted to mention here that I have broken up the large question into four separate questions and included my answers with them.